# jQuery UI : How can I dynamically set the resizable() according to columns

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am resizing the columns on col-md-6 but what If I want to resize the columns on col-md-4, col-md-3 and etc. I have to manually set the script according to the cols. I want to know that how can I set my script dynamically.

Here is my code:

```
var innerDiv1 = $( '.col-md-6' );            
              innerDiv1.resizable({
                handles: 'e',
                minWidth : 430,
                maxWidth : 900,
                resize: function( event, ui ) {
                  var remainingSpace = $(this).parent().width() - $(this).outerWidth(true);
                  console.log('Remaining Space = '+remainingSpace);
                  var divTwo = $(this).next();
                  console.log('Div Two = '+divTwo);
                  var divTwoWidth = remainingSpace - ( divTwo.outerWidth(true) - divTwo.width() );
                  console.log('Div Two Width = ' + divTwoWidth);
                  divTwo.css( 'width', divTwoWidth + 'px' );
                }
              });
```

and here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MyTests/964k4yev/2/) with col-md-6

Updated :  [fiddle col-md-4](https://jsfiddle.net/MyTests/964k4yev/3/), [fiddle col-md-3](https://jsfiddle.net/MyTests/964k4yev/4/)  with col-md-4 and with col-md-3 respectively

The problem is the in col-md-4 and col-md-3 when I resize the last or second cols its automatically comes under it why!

For that I have to make changes evertime in max-width and min-width. I want to make it dynamic. I hope you understand

How can I dynamically set the max and min width for each col-md-*

*Try to resize the columns from east side*

Comment: Where is col-md-4, col-md-3  ? Please put complete fiddle

Comment: You mean all the cols added dynamically should be resizable as it is now ?

Comment: @YoYo Yes, In fiddle with col-md-6 it is working fine but in col-md-4 and col-md-3 it is not working properly I have to make changes everytime manually.

Comment: I see no difference . What do you mean by not working properly ?

Comment: @YoYo the problem is the in col-md-4 and col-md-3 when I resize the last or second cols its automatically comes under it why.

Comment: @YoYo For that I have to make changes evertime in max-width and min-width. I want to make it dynamic. I hope you understand

Comment: if you add borders to both fiddle **col** you will know both are working same https://jsfiddle.net/964k4yev/5/ and https://jsfiddle.net/964k4yev/7/

Comment: @YoYo Yes your are right. The problem is because I have set the min and max width did you tell me how can I dynamically set the max and min width for each col-md-*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146143/discussion-between-user7791702-and-yo-yo).